# How to disable HTTP requests on Heroku and/or auto-redirect to HTTPS?

Tags: scala, http, ssl, heroku, playframework

I'm currently deploying a Scala Play 2.7.x application to Heroku intending only HTTPS access but the HTTP access is still available and then in this case, the authentication doesn't work.

How can I disable HTTP completely for a Scala Play application deployed in Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heroku doesn't handle redirection for you](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls):

> Redirects need to be performed at the application level as the Heroku router does not provide this functionality. You should code the redirect logic into your application.

It looks like this is [relatively straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49871214/354577) with Play Framework version 2.6 or later:

```
play.filters.enabled += play.filters.https.RedirectHttpsFilter
```

If necessary, you [can override](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionConfiguration#Overriding-configuration-with-system-properties) this setting in your development environment by passing `-Dplay.filters.enabled=<whatever>` locally, or [provide an alternate configuration file with `-Dconfig.file`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionConfiguration#Using--Dconfig.file).