# How to change the http into https for my domain name?

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I recently bought a domain name at OVH for an app I hosted on Heroku. I then paid for the dynos in order to set an automatic SSL certificate.

Everything seems to me working fine:

```
Domain       Status       Last Updated
───────────  ───────────  ────────────
mpjrigot.eu  Cert issued  2 minutes
mpjrigot.fr  Cert issued  2 minutes
```

But my URL is still in HTTP. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I'm using React.js for this app

I also have a Ruby on Rails back but for nom i'm keeping that on the heroku.app, works fine

**2nd EDIT**

Using react-https-redirect, force-https or react-ssl-redirect...

Basically, chrome tells me that "this is not a safe space", and that this is a fake https that might want to steal the user's passwords and stuff

So I got an SSL that is set on my HerokuApp,
I got a domain on OVH that points to the IP of the app

But the http isn't secure somehow

I really think I missed something obvious as I'm new to this...

Comment: How are you hosting your React app on Heroku? Production React builds are just static files, and that's not really what Heroku does. How you're hosting your React app will determine the best course of action.

Comment: Well I just deploy my Git Main branch in production, if that's what you mean

Comment: Not really... are you deploying React in development mode or using a production build? Can you show us your `package.json`? Do you have a `Procfile`?

Comment: I fainally got it, switching my domain name from OVH to Gandi... Turns out ovh only takes static IPs which doesn't work on Heroku ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution**

I eventually read about Heroku needing a specific host that takes in the address they tell you to point to when setting a domain name...
So I switched to Gandi for my domain name and set the ALIAS to point to said adress

Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

You can add HTTPS to your app with the following methods.

**Method1 (Recommended)**

Since, you're using rails for the backend, you can configure your rails app to always use HTTPS.

in your production.rb add

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

- More Info: https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls
- ActionDispatch SSL: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionDispatch/SSL.html

**Method2 (Easy Setup)**

You can also signup for cloudflare's free plan and easily setup https redirects with cloudflare's 'Always Use HTTPS' or 'Automatic HTTPS Rewrites' feature.

The 'Always Use HTTPS' feature will redirect all http requests on your site to https address.

The 'Automatic HTTP Rewrites' feature will change the HTTP links on your site to HTTPS links.

More Info here:

- Always use HTTPS: https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-make-your-site-https-only
- Automatic HTTPS: https://www.cloudflare.com/website-optimization/automatic-https-rewrite/
- Cloudflare's SSL: https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/

[cloudflare dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhFPb.png)

Comment: Great, i'll look into that

Although when I speak of back, it's merely a Rest API, I thing i should add something to my React app, don't I ?

Comment: Yes, if that's the case then i think you will have to do that. Maybe checkout these packages: react-https-redirect, force-https and react-ssl-redirect

Comment: Ok so it DOES redirect but my heroku certificate is not recognized so the https redirection is just sending an error.......

Comment: OK, can you give me more details on the error. Maybe something is misconfigured or maybe there's a DNS issue or something of that sort, or maybe SSL certificates are not configured properly. Also, sometimes automatic redirects can lead to a redirect loop if not configured properly.

Comment: Basically, chrome tells me that "this is not a safe space", and that this is a fake https that might want to steal the user's passwords and stuff

So I got an SSL that is set on my HerokuApp
I got a domain on OVH that points to the IP of the app

But the http isn't secure somehow

I really think I missed something obvious as I'm new to this...

Comment: "Since, you're using rails for the backend"—if hosting the front-end _from_ Rails this will work. But if not this will just make the _API_ redirect to HTTPS (this is important, too; likely even more important than getting your client to redirect). There's no need for Cloudflare, but there's also no need for _Heroku_ to host React. Any static file host will do, and most of them let you just flip SSL on.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

Heroku provides a certificate, so you should be able to access your application using `https://`. However [it does *not* redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS for you](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls):

> Redirects need to be performed at the application level as the Heroku router does not provide this functionality. You should code the redirect logic into your application.

Exactly how you do that depends on the language and libraries or framework that you are using. Several common examples are listed in the link I provided above.

If you edit your question to tell us what technology you have used to build your application I'll be happy to add those details to this answer. In case you are using Scala, please see [How to disable HTTP requests on Heroku and/or auto-redirect to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60231303/354577)